# Can someone please explain what this bit of javascript code is doing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

So I'm completely new to programming and trying to understand what this piece of javascript code is doing specifically lines 3 and 4 am I right in assuming it's checking the array for the randomly generated number and if it's not present in the array it adds it and then if it's true it will place that number in the document ID?

```js
var numarray = new Array(76);
do {
  var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) + 1;
} while (numarray[rannum]);
numarray[gNumber] = true;
document.getElementById(cellID).innerHTML = rannum;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, it's picking a random number between 1 and 76 and will continue to do so as long as an item in the array that matches the index of the last generated random number has a non-falsy value.

In your case, the array is only declared to have 76 indexed positions, but the array is never populated, so the array is full of `undefined` items.

The `while` part of the loop says that the loop condition is `numarry[random]`, which is a way of testing to see if the item is any "truthy" value (anything that does not implicitly convert to a "false" or "falsy" value like `0`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `false`, `""`). Since your array is full of `undefined` items, the loop condition is not satisfied the very first time it is checked and the loop only winds up iterating once, thereby generating only one random number.

See the comments inline for details.

```js
var numarray = new Array(76);   // Create new array with 76 indexed positions (or, a .length of 76)

// Start a loop
do {
  // Math.random() - Get a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
  // * 76 - Take the random and multiply by 76 to get a random between 0 (inclusive)
  //        and 76 (exclusive)
  // Math.floor()  - Round the number down to the next whole number
  // + 1 - Instead of the range being 0 (inclusive) and 76 (exclusive) add an offset
  //       so that the final number will be between 1 (inclusive) and 77 (exclusive)
  var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) + 1;
} while (numarray[rannum]); // Keep the loop going as long as the array item matching the random
                            // isn't undefined, false, 0, NaN, null or "" (i.e. "truthy").
                            // In this case, the array is empty so the loop will only 
                            // iterate one time.
                            
// Set the array item that matches the gNumber value to true.
// You haven't provided any code that declares or initializes gNumber,
// so this line of code really is meaningless in this context.
numarray[gNumber] = true;

// Change the inner content (HTML and text) of the element with an id that matches
// the value in cellID to the random number
document.getElementById(cellID).innerHTML = rannum;
```

Resources:

- [new Array()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
- [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)
- [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Answer (score 1):

```
var numarray= new Array(76);
```

It will create array with 76 elements,

```
do {
           var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) + 1;
```

This will assign a number with in 76

```
        } while (numarray[rannum]);
```

This will loop through element of rannum is defined, in your case it will undefined always

```js
var numarray= new Array(76);
do {
           var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) + 1;
console.log(rannum);
        } while (numarray[rannum]); 
console.log(numarray)
```